# Efficient way of creating a multi - dim array from coursor

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, multidimensional-array

I'm executing a cursor. I have cutted off the code how the procedure is called and executed. This part is efficient.
At last I have a a not big cursor. I'm calling the procedure, which returns this cursor many times on the page and  I need to create a multidimensional array from it. This array should look like like the following:

```
   $ret = oci_execute($outrefc) ; 
    while ($row = @oci_fetch_array($outrefc))
    {
            foreach (array_keys($row) as $key)
            {

                     $res[$i][$key] = $row[$key];

            }
            $i++;
    }
```

Is there any way to make the upper  snippet faster?
The multidimensional array should stay as it is. I only wonder if I could create it in any more efficient way.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code review.

Comment: Maybe like this: `$ret = oci_execute($outrefc) ; 
    while ($row = @oci_fetch_array($outrefc))
    {
        $res[$i]= $row;
        $i++;
    }`

Comment: @quentino  Thanks! But seems to be exaclty so slow like the other...

Comment: Perhaps the slowness is coming from fetching from the cursor?

Comment: @tbone I have also tried with  `oci_fetch_all($outrefc, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW+OCI_NUM);` . But same result. So can I make fetching faster?

Comment: I think you may need to look at the actual SQL that is being used to fetch from the db

Comment: I have already checked. As written above It is working fine and is fast.